# Is linear dependence dependent on field?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the vector space $\mathbb{C}^3$ and three vectors $x_1 = (1, 0, 0)$, $x_2 = (0, 1, 0)$, $x_3 = (0, 0, 1)$.

Is it correct that these three vectors are linearly independent if $\mathbb{C}^3$ is defined over the field $\mathbb{R}$, while they are linearly dependent if the field is $\mathbb{C}$?

I'm using the following definiton for linear dependence (Halmos, Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces, 2e):

> A finite set of vectors $\{x_i\}$ is linearly dependent if there
>   exists a corresponding set $\{\alpha_i\}$ of scalars, not all zero,
>   such that
>
> $$ \tag{1}\label{eqn_li}\sum_i \alpha_i x_i = 0, $$

and the reason I'm asking is that $\eqref{eqn_li}$
is satisfied for the scalars $\alpha_1 = i$ , $\alpha_2 = 0$, $\alpha_3 = 0$, hence there is a set of scalars $\{\alpha_i\}$, not all zeros, such that $\eqref{eqn_li}$ holds.

Comment: "...for the scalars..." . **What** scalars??

Comment: The given set of scalars doesn't satisfy  (1).

Comment: Hint: $\sum\alpha_jx_j=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those three vectors are linearly independent both over $\mathbb C$ and over $\mathbb R$.

However, $(1,0,0)$ and $(i,0,0)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb C$ and linearly independent over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that $ix_1+0x_2+0x_3=0$ is wrong.
Your three vectors are linearly independent, no matter if we view $\Bbb C^3$ as three-dimensional space over $\Bbb C$, or six-dimensional space over $\Bbb R$ (or e.g., infinite-dimensional space over $\Bbb Q$) in the apparent way.

However, $(1,0,0)$ and $(i,0,0)$ are $\Bbb R$-linearly independant and $\Bbb C$-linearly dependant.